# how to get custom admin submenu( custom post type ) item to highlight when its active

Tags: sub-menu

I have a menu item added using add_menu_page say **ABC**.

I have added a custom post_type **product** as a submenu item under **ABC** I created it with this code

```
add_submenu_page(
    'abc',
    'Products',
    'Products',
    'manage_options',
    'edit.php?post_type=product'
);
```

How to highlight submenu_page **product** if selected in admin menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the above issue by putting "**show_in_menu**" parameter to **false** while registering the Custom-Post-Type **product**.