# Visiting a console submenu page does not expand its parent menu item

Tags: admin-menu, add-submenu-page

*I have moved a custom post taxonomy to another menu item

```
//created a post type that does not appear in admin menu, therefore its taxonomy does not, too
    $args = array(
            'label'                 => 'Item',
            'description'           => 'Store items',
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
            'taxonomies'            => array( 'store-category' ),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => false,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-cart',
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,   
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'product')
        );
    register_post_type( 'tdlrm_store_item', $args );

//registered a taxonomy
$args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'group')
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'store-category', array( 'tdlrm_store_item' ), $args );     

//added a submenu page for the taxonomy into another menu item
   add_action('admin_menu', 'tdlrm_configure_admin_menu1',10);
   function tdlrm_configure_admin_menu1(){
      add_submenu_page('TDLRM', 'category_redirect', 'Categories', 'administrator',  'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store-category&post_type=tdlrm_store_item');
   }
```

When I visit the page, no menu items get expanded, I would like the TDLRM item (previously created) to expand.

*I have created a submenu page for users with a certain role. When I visit the page, it expands the Users menu item.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'tdlrm_configure_admin_menu2',10);
function tdlrm_configure_admin_menu2(){
    add_submenu_page('TDLRM', 'store_users_redirect', 'Store users', 'administrator',  'users.php?role=tdlrm_store_user');
}
```

I would like the TDLRM item to expand instead.

There was also a similar task that I solved while writing this question, although the solution does not apply to the other two.

I have created a custom post type, its slug is 'fp-teaser'. It created an admin menu item with the following slug: 'edit.php?post_type=fp-teaser'.

I then moved the new menu item under another menu item like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'tdlrmm__menu_edit', 20);
function tdlrmm__menu_edit(){
    // removing the page from top-level menu
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=fp-teaser');
    
    // creating the page under My-menu
    // (My-menu is a page I created earlier.)
    add_submenu_page('My-menu', 'Teasers', 'Teasers', 'edit_posts',  'edit.php?post_type=fp-teaser');
}
```

The problem was that when I visited `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=fp-teaser`, no menu item got expanded. What I wanted was the `My-menu` item to expand showing the `Teasers` sub-menu item.

This has been solved after finding [this Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188866/how-to-get-custom-admin-submenu-custom-post-type-item-to-highlight-when-its-a), by setting the `show_in_menu` parameter to `false` while registering the `fp-teaser` post type.

Comment: "the TDLRM item (previously created)" - what's your code for that?

Comment: Hi Sally CJ ) It's in another plugin: `function tdlrm__menu_edit_main(){ add_menu_page( 'TDLRM', 'TDLRM', 'administrator', 'TDLRM', 'tdlrm__settings_page', 'dashicons-cart', 5 ) ;} add_action('admin_menu', 'tdlrm__menu_edit_main',10);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`parent_file` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parent_file/) to ensure the TDLRM menu is expanded when viewing the "Store users" or "Categories" page.

```php
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'wpse_398962_parent_file' );
function wpse_398962_parent_file( $parent_file ) {
    global $submenu_file, $typenow;

    // 1: This is for highlighting the TDLRM » "Store users" submenu.
    if ( 'users.php' === $parent_file && ! $submenu_file &&
        isset( $_GET['role'] ) && 'tdlrm_store_user' === $_GET['role']
    ) {
        $typenow = true; // this trick ensures the parent file/slug is TDLRM

        // This highlights the "Store users" submenu.
        // Make sure it matches the slug you passed to add_submenu_page().
        $submenu_file = 'users.php?role=tdlrm_store_user';

        return 'TDLRM';
    }

    // 2: This is for highlighting the TDLRM » Categories submenu.
    // Make sure the value matches the slug you passed to add_submenu_page().
    if ( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store-category&amp;post_type=tdlrm_store_item' === $submenu_file ) {
        return 'TDLRM';
    }

    return $parent_file;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. There is a trick above which is used for expanding the TDLRM menu, but only when viewing the "Store users" page.

   And what the trick does is, it prevents [`get_admin_page_parent()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_admin_page_parent/) from changing the parent file (`$parent_file`) to `users.php`.
2. WordPress escapes special characters like ampersands (so `&` becomes `&amp;`) in the menu/submenu **slug**, hence your "Categories" submenu needs to use a valid/properly-escaped slug in order for the submenu to be highlighted when viewing the TDLRM » Categories page.

   ```php
   // Note below I used &amp; instead of just &
   add_submenu_page('TDLRM', 'category_redirect', 'Categories', 'administrator',
       'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store-category&amp;post_type=tdlrm_store_item');
   ```

And actually, instead of having to use the `tdlrmm__menu_edit()` function, you could simply set the `show_in_menu` arg to `My-menu` (the menu slug), and then "Teasers" ( or whatever is the (plural) label of your post type ) would appear as a submenu under your "My-menu" menu.

However, be sure to read the note [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_menu) which says, "*this item will become the **first submenu item**, and replace the location of the top-level link. If this isn’t desired, the plugin that creates the menu page needs to set the add_action priority for admin_menu to 9 or lower*".

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm! Oh my, is it possible to know Wordpress like this ))  

Comment: Side note to anyone interested. Note 2 from Sally CJ's answer works with the IF under the comment #2 in the `wpse_398962_parent_file()` function (one highlights the link, the other expands the parent menu item), so in this case I've made two separate filters, one for users and the other for categories.

Comment: Also, on the 'however' part. The `show_in_menu` argument combined with the `add_action` priority works great. However, if we don't want to change the priority (say, the `add_action` is in another plugin), we can remove the new first sumbenu item with `remove_submenu_page()` and add the one we need with `add_submenu_page()` right away, setting the priority on that. The `show_in_menu` argument will highlight the new link and expand its parent menu.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments :)